Get Bluetooth mouse name from command line
I have a shell script that I run periodically to notify me if my Magic Mouse battery is running low (the built-in notification doesn't allow you to customize the threshold, which I find is too low). It uses the following command to get the name of the mouse to use in the notification message:
MOUSENAME=$(ioreg -c AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService -r -l | grep -i 'product.*mouse' | cut -d = -f2 | cut -d \" -f2)

I just upgraded to Sequoia and this no longer works. Does anyone know the equivalent now?
Here is the complete output of ioreg -c AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService -r -l. The name of the mouse is Barry's 2nd Mouse.
+-o AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService  <class AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService, id 0x10000095e, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (5029 ms), retain 9>
  | {
  |   "IOMatchedAtBoot" = Yes
  |   "PrimaryUsagePage" = 65280
  |   "VersionNumber" = 373
  |   "VendorID" = 1452
  |   "Built-In" = Yes
  |   "AccelCalFW Version" = 0
  |   "WakeReason" = "Host (0x01)"
  |   "Product" = "Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad"
  |   "SerialNumber" = "FM7130204TXN4Q8BG+TCT"
  |   "Transport" = "SPI"
  |   "BootLoaderFW Version" = 6
  |   "Manufacturer" = "Apple Inc."
  |   "ActCalFW Version" = 0
  |   "ProductID" = 833
  |   "DeviceUsagePairs" = ({"DeviceUsagePage"=65280,"DeviceUsage"=11})
  |   "IOPersonalityPublisher" = "com.apple.driver.AppleTopCaseDriverV2"
  |   "MTFW Version" = 1321
  |   "MTCalFW Version" = 1
  |   "KeyCalFW Version" = 0
  |   "ForceCalFW Version" = 0
  |   "ReportInterval" = 8000
  |   "VendorIDSource" = 0
  |   "STFW Version" = 373
  |   "HIDEventServiceProperties" = {"HIDMouseKeysOptionToggles"=0,"JitterNoClick"=1,"ActuateDetents"=1,"Dragging"=No,"HIDSlowKeysDelay"=0,"FlipLeftAndRightEdgeGestures"=No,"JitterNoMove"=1,"HIDTrackpadScrollAcceleration"=20480,"HIDInitialKeyRepeat"=500000000,"TrackpadThreeFingerHorizSwipeGesture"=0,"TrackpadThreeFingerDrag"=Yes,"MTGestureConfiguration"={"Version"=1,"Behaviors"=()},"MTGestureConfigurationOverride"={"Version"=1,"Behaviors"=({"BehaviorID"=1})},"HIDPointerAcceleration"=45056,"UserPreferences"=Yes,"HIDDefaultParameters"=Yes,"HIDMouseKeysOn"=0,"HIDF12EjectDelay"=250,"TrackpadHorizScroll"=1,"TrackpadThreeFingerSwipe"=No,"TrackpadFourFingerVertSwipeGesture"=0,"TrackpadTwoFingerFromRightEdgeSwipeGesture"=0,"USBMouseStopsTrackpad"=0,"HIDMouseScrollAcceleration"=65536,"TrackpadThreeFingerTapGesture"=0,"MouseOneFingerDoubleTapGesture"=0,"HIDScrollZoomModifierMask"=0,"TrackpadScroll"=Yes,"HIDUseLinearScalingMouseAcceleration"=0,"Trackpad Jitter Milliseconds"=192,"HIDPointerButtonMode"=2,"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingPairs"=(),"LogLevel"=6,"TrackpadFourFingerHorizSwipeGesture"=1,"HIDTrackpadAcceleration"=57344,"DragLock"=No,"DeviceOpenedByEventSystem"=Yes,"ReportInterval"=0,"TwofingerNoAction"=1,"HIDClickTime"=500000000,"MouseTwoFingerDoubleTapGesture"=0,"HIDMouseAcceleration"=196608,"SecondClickThreshold"=1,"HIDStickyKeysShiftToggles"=0,"TrackpadHandResting"=Yes,"TrackpadFourFingerPinchGesture"=2,"MouseMomentumScroll"=Yes,"TrackpadFiveFingerPinchGesture"=2,"PalmNoAction Permanent"=1,"MouseButtonMode"="TwoButton","TrackpadThreeFingerVertSwipeGesture"=0,"OutsidezoneNoAction When Typing"=1,"ForceSuppressed"=No,"TrackpadCornerSecondaryClick"=0,"MouseButtonDivision"=55,"HIDStickyKeysOn"=0,"HIDStickyKeysDisabled"=0,"EjectDelay"=0,"TrackpadPinch"=No,"FirstClickThreshold"=1,"HIDClickSpace"=(5,5),"PalmNoAction When Typing"=1,"MouseVerticalScroll"=Yes,"version"=1,"MouseHorizontalScroll"=Yes,"BatchInterval"=1,"MouseKeysStopsTrackpad"=0,"migrationDone"=Yes,"TrackpadMomentumScroll"=1,"MouseTwoFingerHorizSwipeGesture"=0,"HIDKeyRepeat"=83333333,"HIDScrollReset"=Yes,"TrackpadTwoFingerDoubleTapGesture"=0,"Clicking"=Yes,"TrackpadRightClick"=No,"TrackpadRotate"=No,"Use Panther Settings for W"=0,"HIDScrollAcceleration"=20480,"HIDFKeyMode"=1}
  |   "CFBundleIdentifier" = "com.apple.driver.AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver"
  |   "IOProviderClass" = "IOHIDInterface"
  |   "LocationID" = 43
  |   "IOClass" = "AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService"
  |   "HIDServiceSupport" = Yes
  |   "CFBundleIdentifierKernel" = "com.apple.driver.AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver"
  |   "ProductIDArray" = (833)
  |   "ColorID" = 1
  |   "CountryCode" = 0
  |   "IOMatchCategory" = "IODefaultMatchCategory"
  |   "PrimaryUsage" = 11
  |   "IOProbeScore" = 7175
  |   "StandardType" = 0
  |   "IOGeneralInterest" = "IOCommand is not serializable"
  | }
  | 
  +-o IOHIDEventServiceUserClient  <class IOHIDEventServiceUserClient, id 0x100000dd6, !registered, !matched, active, busy 0, retain 6>
      {
        "IOUserClientDefaultLockingSetProperties" = Yes
        "IOUserClientDefaultLocking" = Yes
        "IOUserClientCreator" = "pid 719, WindowServer"
        "IOUserClientDefaultLockingSingleThreadExternalMethod" = No
        "IOUserClientEntitlements" = No
        "DebugState" = {"EventQueue"={"NoFullMsg"=0,"tail"=0,"NotificationForce"=0,"NotificationCount"=0,"head"=0}}
      }
      

+-o AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService  <class AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService, id 0x100000f82, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (0 ms), retain 7>
    {
      "IOGeneralInterest" = "IOCommand is not serializable"
      "IOMatchedAtBoot" = Yes
      "LowBatteryNotificationPercentage" = 6
      "PrimaryUsagePage" = 65280
      "BatteryFaultNotificationType" = "MOBatteryFault"
      "HasBattery" = Yes
      "VendorID" = 76
      "VersionNumber" = 785
      "Built-In" = No
      "DeviceAddress" = "bc-89-a7-e9-61-14"
      "BatteryLowPowerDisconnectionNotificationType" = "MOLowBatteryPowerDisconnected"
      "CurrentBatteryPercentNotificationType" = "CurrentBatteryPercent"
      "Product" = 
      "SerialNumber" = "BC:89:A7:E9:61:14"
      "WakeReason" = "Button (0x03)"
      "Transport" = "Bluetooth"
      "BatteryLowNotificationType" = "MOLowBattery"
      "Manufacturer" = "Apple Inc."
      "ConnectionNotificationType" = "MOConnected"
      "ProductID" = 617
      "DeviceUsagePairs" = ({"DeviceUsagePage"=65280,"DeviceUsage"=11},{"DeviceUsagePage"=65280,"DeviceUsage"=20})
      "IOPersonalityPublisher" = "com.apple.driver.AppleTopCaseDriverV2"
      "PoweredOffNotificationType" = "MOOff"
      "MTFW Version" = 1301
      "BD_ADDR" = <bc89a7e96114>
      "BatteryPercent" = 70
      "HostTransportSwitchNotificationType" = "MOTransportSwitch"
      "CriticallyLowBatteryNotificationPercentage" = 3
      "ReportInterval" = 8000
      "RadioFW Version" = 785
      "VendorIDSource" = 1
      "STFW Version" = 2164
      "CFBundleIdentifier" = "com.apple.driver.AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver"
      "IOProviderClass" = "IOHIDInterface"
      "LocationID" = 669606164
      "BluetoothDevice" = Yes
      "IOClass" = "AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService"
      "DisconnectionNotificationType" = "MODisconnected"
      "HIDServiceSupport" = No
      "ProductIDArray" = (617)
      "CFBundleIdentifierKernel" = "com.apple.driver.AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver"
      "BatteryStatusFlags" = 0
      "IOMatchCategory" = "IODefaultMatchCategory"
      "ColorID" = 0
      "IOProbeScore" = 7175
      "CountryCode" = 0
      "PrimaryUsage" = 11
      "BTFW Version" = 785
    }

The battery percentage correctly appears in the line
      "BatteryPercent" = 70

System Information > Bluetooth contains:
  Connected:
  Barry’s 2nd Mouse:
  Address:  BC:89:A7:E9:61:14
  Vendor ID:    0x004C
  Product ID:   0x0269
  Firmware Version: 3.1.1
  Minor Type:   Mouse
  Services: 0x800020 < HID ACL >
  MX Keys:
  Address:  F0:48:04:89:5A:6A
  Vendor ID:    0x046D
  Product ID:   0xB35B
  Battery Level:    100%
  Firmware Version: MPK12.01_0013
  Minor Type:   Keyboard
  Services: 0x400000 < BLE >


Works for me. Try cutting back the pipes until you get the output you expect.

When I run just the ioreg command, I don't see the mouse name anywhere in it.

I assume the mouse is working. Does it appear in the Bluetooth menu in the menu bar? What about System Information? Do other BT devices appear in the ioreg output?

The mouse is working, it's in the menu, and I can get its battery percentage from ioreg output (although it's not in precisely the same location, so I had to tweak that code). Only the name is missing.

@LincD. I've added the complete output of the ioreg command.

That output looks normal apart from the missing name. Again, does it show up in the Bluetooth menu and in System Information? If so, can you rename the mouse in the BT settings panel?

Yes, it's in the menu and System Information.

You seem to have triggered a bug in Sequoia, though not one that I can reproduce. I would first try changing the name of the mouse. Failing that, I would reboot, first in normal mode, then in safe mode. Beyond that, I don’t know what to suggest, other than to report the bug.

it's not serious enough, I can just hard-code "Mouse" in the script.
